# UITableView Sections like Contacts App

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In the Contacts App, when you scroll through your address book, the letter seems to stay above that section.  This picture is taken as I switch through P and Q contacts [image]

How is this done?  I thought this was default behavior but I realized after implementing my section headers it is not.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: This is the default for `UITableViewStylePlain`, not `UITableViewStyleGrouped`.

Comment: That is exactly how my section headers function, perhaps the bug is in your section header implementation?

Comment: @Evan Mulawski Thanks.  Want to put your answer in so I can mark the question as answered.

Comment: @Crystal Answered. Glad I good help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you described is the default for a `UITableView` that has style `UITableViewStylePlain`. If you have `UITableViewStyleGrouped`, this will not occur.